# How to add a class to a render :partial => @collection on every 4th item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have 16 results

On every 4th item I need to add a class "no-margin" (because every item on the left needs a margin right to create spacing but the last one doing that would break the layout, thus the need for this).

What's the best way to do this?

I have it very rails-like right now.

```
render :partial => @collection

_collection.html.haml
 stuff
```

Is there something that I can put in the partial that would solve this or would it have to happen outside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you render a collection, Rails creates an hidden index. In this case, you can combine the module with the index to obtain the result.

```
# _partial.html.erb
<div class="<% if (partial_counter % 4) == 0 %>no-margin<% end %>">
  ...
</div>

# action
<%= render => "partial", :collection => @collection %>
```

Even better, extract the logic into a Helper method.

Note. The name of the counter is `<partial_name>_counter`.

Comment: The problem with this is that the counter starts at 0...so this actually doesn't work to try to add something to every 4th item. It adds it to the 1st, 5th, 9th, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use cycle() to do this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001753

Not sure whether it would look different in haml, but in an erb template, I would do this:

```
<% @collection.each do |item| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('yes-margin', 'yes-margin', 'yes-margin', 'no-margin' %>">
      ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to use the `each_with_index` method from `enumerable`.

```
# app/views/questions/index.html.haml
- @questions.each_with_index do |question, index|
  %li{ :class => no_margin(index) }
    = render :partial => 'question', :object => question
```

Your helper might look like this.

```
# app/helpers/questions_helper.rb
def no_margin(index)
  index % 4 == 0 ? 'no-margin' : 'margin'
end
```